# Create Method in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, frameworks

Why does entity framework generate Create method for entities that takes parameter for the column that is defined as an identity in database? It makes Create method totally useless as it cannot be used to create entity or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set **StoreGeneratedPattern** as **Identity** on the property tab of your entity primary key property.

Source : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283139.aspx (chapter *Entity Keys and Added Objects*)

Comment: I already did this, but you could set this value after code generation and the parameter still in the method signature. But, I understood from the article above that it creates entity instance with temporary id which is null or 0 that it changes after database update to real value. I think it is not very elegant way, it is obviously workaround not actual solution. Create method should have overloaded signature that doesn't ask identity.